# Accessing credit card info stored in iCloud Keychain (iOS 7)

Tags: ios7, keychain, icloud-api

I wonder if it is possible to get the credit card information stored in the iOS 7 iCloud keychain from within my iOS App. I want users can make payments using the App (physical goods), but I do not want to deal with this kind of sensitive data in my servers or in the App. As far as I have understood in the document linked below, credit card information can be accessed the same way I can access to password information, is that right?

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW1